# EXCEL VBA Store / Save entire row in an array?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Have recieved help how to search in a column for a string, and then store it in an array. Is it possible to store the entire Row? Have searched for it but can't find it.

I want to search in one Sheet that contains data by a string. Then copy those rows that contains that string to another sheet.

My code looks like this.

```
Set wsRaw = Worksheets("raw_list")
Set phaseRange = wsRaw.Columns(PhaseCol)

SearchString = "start"
Set aCell = phaseRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    ReDim Preserve arrStart(nS)
    arrStart(nS) = aCell.Row
    nS = nS + 1
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = phaseRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Row = bCell.Row Then Exit Do
            ReDim Preserve arrStart(nS)
            arrStart(nS) = aCell.Row
            nS = nS + 1
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop
Else
End If
```

Thankfull for any help :)

Comment: In the above code you are storing the row number where a match is found. Why do you want to store the entire row contents in the array. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In one sheet i have these "cases" that are in different phases. Each case is one Row. So that I want to achieve is to search that sheet for a certain phase and then store those cases that are in that phase in an array if it is possible, so i can call for them later. Sorry for my bad english and lack to inform what i mean.

Comment: In that case you don't need to store the entire row :) You can store the Row numbers as you are doing and then later on retrieve the row details from the row numbers.

Comment: Wich function would I use to do that? And thanks again for your quick replies.

Comment: To retrieve the rows data you can use this `Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(arrStart(i))`

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that code. Does it just select the rows in that sheet or is it copied? As you may understand I do not have that much knowlege about vba.

If I want to just print it out on Sheet2 shall I use a For loop?

So grateful for your help

Comment: Since i know what you are doing now, can I suggest you an alternative easy and faster way which doesn't use Arrays to copy your data?

Comment: Yes that would be nice. The reason i wanted to use arrays whas that I then would be able to only do one search and then store them there. So then when I wanted to access the information a new search wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are copying data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on your search criteria in a relevant column then then I would suggest using Autofilter.

See this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsRaw As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim PhaseCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim phaseRange As Range, rng As Range

    strSearch = "start"

    '~~> Change this to the relevant column
    PhaseCol = 1

    Set wsRaw = Sheets("raw_list")

    With wsRaw
        LastRow = .Range(Split(Cells(, PhaseCol).Address, "$")(1) & _
                  .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set phaseRange = wsRaw.Range( _
                                    Split(Cells(, PhaseCol).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                    "1:" & _
                                    Split(Cells(, PhaseCol).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                    LastRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and copy visible rows
        With phaseRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
            Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            '~~> Chnage Sheet2 to the relevant sheet name where you want to copy
            rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1)
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But let's say hypothetically that I would continue to use my arrays. Is it possible to check the row you have searched up and then copy certain columns to another sheet?

Comment: Yes :) `Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(arrStart(i)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(r)`

Comment: I sense I do something terribly wrong :) I have succeded to write out the array in a different sheet. But when I try to copy the rows, only the last row appears. 
`code For i = 1 To 1000 
Sheets("raw_list").Rows(arrStart(i)).Copy 
Sheets("DataSheet").Rows (r) 
Sheets("DataSheet").Select Range("A1").Select 
ActiveSheet.Paste Application.CutCopyMode = False 
Next `

Comment: Never mind :) I found where I ha done wrong. Thank ou so much for your help